# ReportViewer looping ajax calls to keep session alive causes Firefox to look like it's constantly reload

Tags: report, reportviewer

In the HTML generated by the ReportViewer there is the following line of code,

```
setTimeout("frames['ctl00_templateContentPlaceholder_RptVwrTouchSession0'].location.replace('\\\/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Mode=true&ReportID=2649539aa5ca4b63ae81dc879a82ae33&ControlID=80797a28ba484c3e87a5a6ad5527403a&Culture=1033&UICulture=1033&ReportStack=1&OpType=SessionKeepAlive&TimerMethod=KeepAliveMethodctl00_templateContentPlaceholder_RptVwrTouchSession0&CacheSeed=' + encodeURIComponent(Date()));", 0);function KeepAliveMethodctl00_templateContentPlaceholder_RptVwrTouchSession0() {setTimeout("frames['ctl00_templateContentPlaceholder_RptVwrTouchSession0'].location.replace('\\\/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?Mode=true&ReportID=2649539aa5ca4b63ae81dc879a82ae33&ControlID=80797a28ba484c3e87a5a6ad5527403a&Culture=1033&UICulture=1033&ReportStack=1&OpType=SessionKeepAlive&TimerMethod=KeepAliveMethodctl00_templateContentPlaceholder_RptVwrTouchSession0&CacheSeed=' + encodeURIComponent(Date()));", -64831072);}
```

When the `Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd` is called it makes a GET request that returns the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">parent.KeepAliveMethodReportViewer1TouchSession0();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, in effect it becomes a recursive function and because `KeepAliveMethodReportViewer1TouchSession0` calls a set timeout with a negative timeout value, in Firefox it is called immediately, in about 10 seconds Firebug logs over 150 GET requests in one minute there are over 700 requests logged.

If anyone knows how to adjust the timeout on the keepalive request please help.

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the session timeout in my web.config. This resolved the issue. I dont know how that works yet.